# how do I delete all emails from a certain address

Tags: email, outlook-web-app

I have to delete all emails from a certain origin (like foo@bar.com).

I receive a lot of emails from foo@bar.com and I may not use a spam filter, I need to receive them and know they are there (in detail, they are from a batch system on a cluster). Once they are there, they cram my mailbox, so I want to delete them. Handpicking is a little less nice, since we are talking about a few hundreds.

I am currently employing outlook web app for a university mail address, but I am happy with any kind of solution really. So, is there an easy application, that can be hooked up to a mail account and delete all emails from a specific origin? Or can Outlook web app be made to do it? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make a rule and delete the email from particular sender then do the following steps

- Please select the email that you want to delete all emails from this sender address.
- Click Home > Rules > Always Move Messages From, and your selected email sender has been added after the function.
- Then a Rules and Alerts dialog box will display, and specify the Deleted Items folder to place the emails.
- And then click OK button, the emails which are from the same sender in the Inbox have been moved to the Deleted Items folder.
- After removing the emails, you need to go to the Manage Rules & Alerts to turn off the rule that you have created just now, you can select the rule item and click Delete to remove it, or uncheck the rule. And then click OK to close the dialog box

see the details with screenshot at : [this link](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/1247-outlook-delete-all-emails-from-sender.html#a1)

Comment: This does not delete other emails, it only deletes the one selected and blocks future emails

Comment: Follow the link, you must be doing something wrong.

Comment: @RanjitSingh Maybe *you* have not tried it in *outlook web app*. The link you provided is for the desktop app. I have performed the steps and they do not work.

Comment: And the question asked about the web app.